# Can you use an IF function within a Gsheets data validation dropdown menu

Tags: java, function, if-statement, google-sheets, dropdown

I have a list of items within a drop down on Gsheets.

I'd the default to be blank, and if another cell says 'Pending', I'd like the dropdown to automatically also say 'Pending'.

I'd also then like the user to be able to change the item with another option in the list.

I've tried choosing a data range with the function under data validation.

Basically I'd like the dropdown choices to be:

1. =IF(A2="Pending", "Pending", "")
2. In Progress
3. Done

Is this possible within Gsheets, or even using App Script?

I'd like the cell to default to blank, then change to pending based off another cell saying pending.

At the moment it doesn't seem to be dynamic in the sense that it updates when the chosen cell says Pending.

Comment: Is it at all possible to share your sheet? Even an anonymised version would do.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria Here's a quick version I threw together. Basically I'd like the A column on sheet 2 to automatically change to Pending if column G on Sheet 1 says pending, but with the dropdown still containing all options. Thanks! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vVOKlOgO2YS5oMIXOQgTIT6VsMGpxSuebHY4DZhsAPE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you mean Column F on Sheet 1 :) Also, you can either have the column dictated by a formulae or by a user input but not both - referring to your expected outcome for "A column on sheet 2" (which is currently a drop down). You can have data validation (aka. drop downs) setup for those columns that are dictated by a formulae as well; however, a better alternative for your needs would be to use Apps Script's `onEdit` function to determine what sheet 2's column A would indicate, based on sheet 1's column F.